# How to scatter plot two concentric circles with Numpy and Matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, geometry, scatter-plot

I'm trying to recreate the following plot with **Numpy** and **Matplotlib** as part of a question, but I'm struggling to get the "random aspect" of the plot:

[image: this plot]

I've already managed to create the two circles and plot them with this code:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

r = [5, 10]
angle = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)

X = [r[0] * np.cos(angle), r[1] * np.cos(angle)]
Y = [r[0] * np.sin(angle), r[1] * np.sin(angle)]

plt.axis('equal');
plt.scatter(X[0], Y[0], c='purple');
plt.scatter(X[1], Y[1], c='yellow');
```

[image]

But I don't know how to make them get this **random** scattering, like in the example image. I know I need to use Numpy's random number generation, but I don't know how or where to use it, exactly.

Comment: Try generating a random sample in some range for the radius of each point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need more than 100 points, so let's say

```
t = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 1000, endpoint=False)
```

You have the right idea regarding how to build a circle, so add a random radius to each point:

```
r = np.random.uniform([[4], [9]], [[6], [11]], size=(2, 1000))
```

This is not necessarily the best way to do it, since the points will be biased towards the center, but it suffices to illustrate the idea.

```
plt.scatter(r[0] * np.cos(t), r[0] * np.sin(t))
plt.scatter(r[1] * np.cos(t), r[1] * np.sin(t))
```

On second inspection of your images, you may want to replace `np.random.uniform` with `np.random.normal` with a standard deviation of 1.

Comment: You were right, using the Normal Distribution and 600 points, I got a result closer to the reference plot. Thanks!

Comment: @WesleyAlves. Good to know I've been doing this enough to where I can just eyeball what's happening :)

Answer (score 1):

You just have to add randomness to the radius (on limits set by the user).

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# r_start = [5, 10]   make the radius random (any distribution)
r = np.random.uniform([[4.5], [9.5]], [[5.5], [10.5]], size=(2, 100))
angle = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi , 100 )

X = [r[0] * np.cos(angle), r[1] * np.cos(angle)]
Y = [r[0] * np.sin(angle), r[1] * np.sin(angle)]

plt.axis('equal')
plt.scatter(X[0], Y[0], c='purple')
plt.scatter(X[1], Y[1], c='yellow')
plt.show()
```

example output:

[image]

Comment: It worked!! Thanks! As suggested by @MadPhysicist, i had to use more points and use the normal distribution to get a result closer to the reference, but your code also gave a satisfactory result!!

Comment: Yes, @MadPhysicist answer is useful too. Glad to help.